# Getting "negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request:" error not sure why

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, rewrite

I'm currently trying to transfer a site to a new server running Ubuntu 12.10. The site worked fine on the old server, however, the new server is giving me some problems.

When I access the site, I get a white page. After viewing the source, I see that it begins to load the page, then stops.

I looked at the Apache error log and saw the following error:

```
negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request:
```

I searched around and saw some references to URL rewriting. Not sure if that's correct, but I've included the rewrite below:

```
# Always use www in the domain
# Replace 'example.com' with your domain name
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule dir/location http://www.mydomain.com/dir/location[R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#####################################
# the first part of this file is used if you configure your scuttle for nice urls
# (see $cleanurls in config.inc.php)
#####################################


# Rewrite clean URLs onto real files
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?(.*)$ /$1.php/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+) /api/$1_$2.php
</IfModule>


#####################################
# This second part is used to speed-up the application
#####################################

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 15 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 15 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 15 days"
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 15 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 15 days"
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
#<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
#</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

Disable [content negociation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html), at least from your .htaccess by changing `Options +FollowSymlinks` to `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`.

PS : a space is missing before flags on your first rewrite rule

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and it didn't help...